# Can I install ubuntu 22.04 on rather old laptop MSI GP70-2PE?

Tags: software-installation

I have  20.04.6 LTS installed on my  rather old laptop MSI GP70-2PE (GP702PE-426XUA)

```
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
5.15.0-53-generic
x86_64
```

I see in hard info :

https://prnt.sc/keAH_wqF18tV
https://prnt.sc/uCm6oUaZLDbL
https://prnt.sc/gvHEKa-hndt9

and I want to install 22.04 and wonder is my laptop NOT too old for 22.04 version ?
Are there something that I need to pay more attention on istallation ?

Comment: FYI:  The 5.15 kernel is the GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so you're already seeing how that works on your hardware (your 20.04 system is currently using the HWE kernel stack). Whilst Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop media defaults to HWE (*thus currently the 6.2 kernel*), GA kernel stack ISO/media is available; though kernel stacks can be changed post-install.  FYI:  I'm running a QA-test install on a box from 2005 now, and using a Ubuntu *flavor* of *mantic* (what will be 23.10 on release!)

Answer (score 0):

Not too old. But it won't hurt if you test Ubuntu 22.04 in a live environment loaded from a USB stick